# How to change windows 10 power options from registry?

Tags: windows-10, windows-registry

I am trying to change the action taken by windows when I close my laptop lid by changing the values stored in the registry location:

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Power\PowerSettings\4f971e89-eebd-4455-a8de-9e59040e7347\5ca83367-6e45-459f-a27b-476b1d01c936`

Through the DWORDS `DCSettingIndex` and `ACSettingIndex`

But it has no effect, it looks like the registry has nothing to do with the options I choose in the control panel. I am changing these options using a script so it would be better if I did it through the registry.

It is my first time to deal with registry so please till my if I am doing something wrong.

Comment: The registry is not a user tool and it is never better to use the registry than to use the power commands or GUI interface (readily available and work).

Comment: given you want to script this, just use `powercfg /change ... ` to make changes to the settings. See `powercfg /?` in a command prompt for all parameters.

Answer (score 0):

AS @John states, generally, do not use the Registry for something better handled through the OS tools. That said, if you want to *copy* the portion of the Registry concerned with power options to restore later,

- Make any needed changes using the *Power Options* CPL.
- Open *Regedit* and go to the key you want to save.

[image: Exporting Registry Key]

- Right-click on the key and select *Export*.
- Name the file as you wish and save it.

Should the *Power Options* get changed,just run the .reg file to restore the key to the saved settings.

It is also possible to examine the .reg file, but a mistake in *editing* it can be dangerous, making the OS unusable.